# How do I create a relationship between two nodes using C# Neo4jClient?

Tags: c#, graph, neo4j, neo4jclient, nosql

I'm new to the Neo4j scene, but when attempting to create a relationship between a playlist and a song I get the following C# error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Neo4jClient.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

C# Code:

```
client.Cypher
    .Match("(song1:Song)", "(playlist1:Playlist)")
    .Where((Song song1) => song1.Name == newSong.Name)
    .AndWhere((Playlist playlist1) => playlist1.Name == newPlaylist.Name)
    .Create("(playlist1)-[r:CONTAINS_SONG]->(song1)")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Objects `newSong` and `newPlaylist` are seeded with data from a file and already exist in the Neo4j database. When using the live debugger I see `newSong.Name` is equal to "Goodbye In Her Eyes" and `newPlaylist.Name` is equal to "Adam Country". These values both exist in the Neo4j database (below). Using `.Query.QueryText` gives the same error as well. I'm using `neo4j-community-3.0.0-M03` and `Neo4jClient 1.1.0.28`.

I've created my own query that works, but I feel like there is a disconnect between the C# code and the actual query that is being output. The following works:

```
MATCH (song1:Song),(playlist1:Playlist)
WHERE song1.Name = 'Goodbye In Her Eyes' AND playlist1.Name = 'Adam Country'
CREATE (playlist1)-[r:CONTAINS_SONG]->(song1)
```

Neo4j Browser Text Output:

```
+==============================+
|n                             |
+==============================+
|FullName: Adam Country.txt    |
|Name: Adam Country            |
+------------------------------+
|Artist: Zac Brown Band        |
|FullName: Goodbye In Her Eyes |
|Name: Goodbye In Her Eyes     |
+------------------------------+
```

What should my C# code look like to accomplish this relationship?

```
[Playlist "Adam Country"] CONTAINS_SONG [Song "Goodbye In Her Eyes"]
```

Comment: Have you initialized the client?

Comment: Your `C#` code looks fine to me, I've taken it directly and run it through LinqPad against a `2.3x` and `3.0x` DB instance, and in both cases, no problems. Could you show your `Song` and `Playlist` classes please?

Answer (score 1):

If newSong and newPlaylist are initialised the most likely explanation is that the Client is not initialised.
Do you create an instance of GraphClient and then call Connect?

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();
```

Comment: You would get an `InvalidOperationException` not a `NullReferenceException` if the client is not initialized.

Comment: if the client is not assigned to a new GraphClient, you would get a NullReferenceException

Comment: I see what you're saying now - though as the `NullReferenceException` is thrown from the `Neo4jClient.dll` - the `GraphClient` would have to have been instantiated for it to know.

Comment: Ah, OK Chris, yes I agree with you. Caesar - What is the type of PlayList.Name and Song.Name? If they are nullable a NullReferenceException can occur is any of the Song or PlayList have a null value in Neo4j.